# umount device or mount point?

Tags: mount, umount

Is there a more-correct way to unmount a device/filesystem/etc?  Should I umount the device I originally mounted or the mount point?

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/myusbstick
do stuff
umount /mnt/myusbstick
```

OR

```
umount /dev/sda1
```

Answer (score 6):

On Linux, the recommended way (according to the util-linux maintainers)<sup>[citation neeed]</sup> is to use `umount <mountpoint>`, for several reasons:

- The same device may be mounted on multiple locations, e.g. using bind mounts, *btrfs* subvolumes, or FUSE filesystems; you don't know which one would be unmounted first.

  (You can use `umount --all-targets <device>` though.)
- A mount might have *multiple* backing devices, for filesystems such as btrfs, and `umount` won't necessarily understand all of them (as the mtab & mountinfo files only show one).
- The backing device might be not what you think it is. For example, `mount foo.iso /mnt` will set up a loop device and mount *that*. (Though, luckily, `umount foo.iso` is also smart enough to look up the corresponding loop device.)
- You can stack several mounts on the same location, with only the latest one being visible.

Comment: and can you clarify which is the mount point?  e.g a or b of `mount a b`?

Comment: The mountpoint is the directory, so `b`.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter which way you refer to the mount.

The only case where it makes a difference is when you have a device mounted to multiple mount points. In that case when you specify the device to the umount command, it'll unmount the most recently mounted mountpoint. Specifying a mountpoint will allow unmounting that specific mountpoint.